# How to visualize scales?

Tags: scales, practice

I am trying to become a more versatile musician, and I am pretty sure being able to in some way imagine where on a scale the notes, that I am playing are located is an important part of that.

This problem is probably not as apparent for pianists, because which scale degree a finger is on is probably more obvious, but I imagine many melody instruments, like flutes or saxophones or stringed instruments like my guitar make this necessity more obvious.

I want to be able to not think    a' cis'' e'' gis'' if I am playing the first bar of Saties Gymnopédie No. 1, but the fourth, the sixth, the first and the third degree of the scale (in this case e major) or at least represent them this way in my head and their relation to each other and the scale as a whole.

At the moment what I do is:

I am basically trying to imagine the notes on an abstracted guitar neck that has only twelve notes and repeats from there, but it's hard to stay precise. 
Possibly a Piano keyboard with the root just being the c on the keybord would be better, as it has more structure, although this is not ideal as I am learning a bit of piano as well...

To the professional or very good musicians out there. Do you visualize/imagine the scale/notes in some way like that? If so how? If this question does not make sense to you I would be happy to clarify.

EDIT: Imagine I am a Jazz Saxophonist, the CAGED System and all that kind of stuff is well known to me but not at all what I am talking about here, I think the reference to me playing the guitar is muddying the waters with all that baggage of scale shapes, this is explicitly not what I am trying (and seemingly failing) to ask about, as it only pertains to the guitar.

Comment: The question is a little flawed - in key E, the notes do not correlate to those of key C. So your 2nd para. isn't making sense.

Comment: Is it better now? I know the notes don't correlate, but the scale degrees, should right?

Comment: The second paragraph is now the third I hope it's more readable that way.

Comment: Hm, do you want to be able to pick out the degrees *by ear* (i. e. when listening to the music), or "by eye" when reading the score? I'd also say that often tracing the individual notes is needlessly complicated, e. g. in your example, I would just think of it as the Amaj7 = IVmaj7 chord.

Comment: FWIW, I've played melodies and chords by ear enough to have developed an emotional feeling for scale degrees. I don't have to think about their names, they're like actors in a drama plot or rooms in a house. You feel it, you know what and where, and where everything else is in relation. If you constantly have to think about which actor plays the main character and who is who in the plot, then the drama isn't meaningful enough to you. Or if you're like "is this the _toilet_ or the _kitchen_", you haven't spent enough time living and operating in the house. It's the same with scale degrees. :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - do like the analogy!

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica sure but that's like saying to someone don't look at the letters, read the story. It's one step after the other, right? I have to start some where, In a few years maybe I can do it like that.

Comment: @Ramillies No this is more about playing, both improvising and playing sheet music. I am not thinking of the note names, but of the positions in the scale, but What I want to know is, how  really good musicians, imagine/visualize these scale degrees in relation to the whole scale or even all surrounding notes. Or even if they do it at all. (I would guess so but what do I know)

Comment: You may find answers to you question here:

https://www.jazzadvice.com/visualization-for-jazz-improvisation/

and/or here:

https://www.jazzadvice.com/visualization-for-jazz-improvisation-ebook/

Jazzadvice in general is great and they often mention how important visualization is.

Comment: The page has a galaxy brain meme so it seems legit. I'll have a read later thanks^^

Comment: @pindakaas Not at all. You can develop a sensitivity to scale degrees through playing and listening. Many people feel the tonic, the home note, more easily than other degrees. Play a cadence with chords A - D - E7 - A, establishing A major key. Then play an A note. Repeat the cadence and play an E note. Play notes A, E, A, E, do they feel similar or different? They are the 1st and 5th scale degrees. Then play the cadence and play a D note, then C#. You felt something, didn't you? Play melodies by ear and feel the notes. The same for chords, arpeggiate chord tones of songs and taste the notes.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica shure this sounds like a great exercise, I have done things at least roughly in the same direction, like interval training and singing scales  and stuff. But I guess my question aims at the other direction basically of knowing what I am playing and learing to hear from there (basically a two pronged attack on the problem..) . It works so far as I find myself finding the "right" notes more intuitively, but I have the feeling that I could use tips on how to imagine/visualize a scale...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : this answer was made before any edits to the question!

Knowledge of at least some of the scale *patterns* is your answer. On guitar, there is the unique factor that doesn't occur on any other instruments, except bass guitar.

If you know just one scale pattern, let's say the two octaves that start on 6th string fret 5, then 7, then 5th string, fret 4,5,7 etc - giving an A major scale across all six strings. By moving that same pattern up a fret, you have the scale notes freom B♭ major, and so on.

Now, the degrees of the scale are viewed from a different perspective. Let's say you play notes 1, 3 5 in key A. That's 6th string 5th fret, 5th string 4 and 7th frets. To play the same tune in B♭, just move iyt all up one fret. To play in key C, start on 6th string, 8th fret, but retain the same *relative* pattern.

So once you establish a tune in one key, it's straightforward to transpose to other keys.

When you are familiar with that pattern, find a different one, and work it similarly. Soon, you'll be able to hear the different intervals, which relate to parts of a pattern. Then, you'll be able to transfer a phrase from one pattern to another.

It may be easier to start with the pentatonics, as they form easy patterns on guitar necks.

Comment: I think I may not have made myself clear, I am trying to get an imagination of scales basically independent from the instrument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not convinced your question makes much sense.  For one thing,  music is loaded with accidentals and modulations (effectively key changes or major/minor stuff).   Rather than worrying about where you are in the tonic scale, try to think about the current phrase and the  absolute intervals between notes.  It certainly helps to know that, e.g., the next chunk of notes are a run  in D-melodic minor, but overall what you need to be able to do is "know" the melody and chord structure in your head. And without consciously assigning Solfege or chord names/numbers as you go.

Comment: Interesting, but if you are improvising in a scale for example, are you not aware, where in the context of the scale the notes are that you are playing? If you  are aware do you not see/hear/imagine this somehow in you mind?

Comment: If the tonal center modulates, you just do everything relative to the new center. That presents no problem at all. It's totally commonplace. @pindakaas, yes, you would be aware of the changing context of scale tones if the music modulates (or temporarily tonicizes a new center.)

Comment: But could you share how you are aware of this in your mind? Do you see a violin string in your minds eye and the notes you are playing in relation to the tonic, do you see numbers, hears intervals related to this tonic? This is probably something most people don't do consciously at least that is the feeling all these answers give me. ^^

Comment: @pindakaas, look for my answer on this page, I gave you my outline how I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very guitar-centric question and you are asking for "visualization" so I'll give you some tips on that.  But I will also deviate from your question.

Given that the guitar is tuned to standard tuning there are a set of pattern that essentially stay in position and cross all 6 strings (I should have stated that this is not in reference to the 7 string guitar, etc).  These patterns interlock up the neck from one position to the other.  Starting with the 7 diatonic modes the 5 that I find myself using most often are Locrean, Dorian, Phrygian, Mixolydian, and Aeolian (minor).  The reason for this affinity is that they also line up with a chord form from the CAGED system.  This covered the entire terrain of the neck.  As an example the Locrean mode can be played with the following finger pattern with one finger per consecutive fret,

string 6 --- 1, 2, 4

string 5 --- 1, 2, 4

string 4 --- 1, 3, 4

string 3 --- 1, 3, 4

string 2 --- 2, 4

string 1 --- 1, 2, 4

The second octave is at finger 1 on string 1.  Starting on the second note you have the Ionian mode or major scale.  The pattern does NOT depend on where you start.  It is a movable pattern and once mastered the guitarist can read and play in any key just by aligning Do, the second not of Locrian with the appropriate fret (corresponding to the key name).  For example, you want to play in Db just make sure that your index finger is one the 8th fret (C) and this will be C Locrian = Db Major.  Similar patterns exist for the other modes.  Once you have the standard forms down and understand how they overlap you can weave in and out of them all.  It is a common practice on the guitar at least to commit 3 note per string patterns to memory as they lend themselves to fast consecutive picking patterns. These typically shift away from the original position.  A third way to "visualize" scale patterns on the guitar is to realize that the strings can be grouped into pairs, (E, A), (D, G), (B, E), and that everything repeats up an octave when you shift 2 frets from group 1 to group 2 and then shift by 3 frets from group 2 to group 3.  Yet another way to visualize is to see the whole step half step pattern one a single string.  The pattern will need to be shifted for each new key.

Scales are built from simpler objects called tetrachords.  The major scale, for example is the same tetrachord played once at a starting note then repeated a whole step up from where you stop, e.g. in terms of intervals (W - W - H) - W - (W - W - H).  Additionally the 7 diatonic modes are all related to the Major scale.  Hence, once you have all the basic 4 note patterns in your muscle memory and develop a good ear you can navigate you way around the neck without the visualization aspect associated with scales.  Some would consider that a much better approach to fret board mastery.

Since you asked what we do as part of your question I will answer that directly.  My guitar teacher encouraged me to "visualize" the scale, and chord, patterns on the fret board, and I did.  At this point I "feel" my way around.  I don't really think I use visualization when I play.  I do sometimes close my eyes and visualize the sheet music if I'm still trying to memorize a piece but truthfully once that happens, or if I'm improvising, I go from sound to movement.  I cannot say that the visualization exercises I was taught did or didn't help w/r to developing the ability to feel my way around the guitar.  I believe it did help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're grappling with is *the relative interval relationships and function of scale tones.*

There are several ways to describe those interval relationships:

- intervals above/below the *tonic* (the first tone of the scale) is probably the commonest
- the interval size between steps of the scale (whole and half steps, and augmented seconds) this and the first are surely the most common ways to describe the intervals within a scale

Along with those two things you want to learn the scale degree nomenclatures like *tonic*, *supertonic*, *mediant*, etc. and solfege like *DO*, *RE*, *MI*, etc.

Some other ways to think about it:

- scales are two tetrachords (4 tone, scale like segments) separated by a perfect fifth. There are four tetrachord types: major, minor, harmonic, phrygian. With a tonic of `C` the tetrachords would start on `C` and `G`. All the combinations of tetrachords starting on those two tones (major+major, minor+major, etc. etc.) will produce a wide variety of scale. The nice thing is a fairly simple idea - four tetrachords - produces lots of scales. You need a good amount of basic theory under your belt to really understand this. Think of it like scale study, phase II.
- scales can be viewed as *filling in a tonic chord*. Start with a major or minor chord then label the chord tones with their *scale degree numbers*. Ex. `C` major, start with the tonic chord `C E G C` labeled with scale degree numbers `^1 ^3 ^5 ^1`...
- `^1` steps up/down from `^2`
- `^3` steps up/down from `^4`
- `^5` steps up/down from `^6`
- the high `^` steps down/up from `^7`

`^1 ^3 ^5 ^1` plus the filling in tones `^2 ^4 ^6 ^7` gives you a complete scale. A nice bonus with this view is the tones are basically group into the stable tones of the tonic chord and *tendency tones* and their characteristic movements. This knowledge is valuable in harmony and voice leading. This also involves a basic theory foundation and might be a scale study, phase II topic.

> I want to be able to not think a' cis'' e'' gis'' if I am playing the first bar of Saties Gymnopédie No. 1, but the fourth, the sixth, the first and the third degree of the scale (in this case e major) or at least represent them this way in my head and their relation to each other and the scale as a whole.

This is exactly what you *should* do. You want to think in *relative term*.

Applying some of the ideas above to *Gymnopédie No. 1* (my copy is in `D` with a key signature of two sharps) you will see for example...

- The first bass note `G` is not the *tonic* but the *subdominant* - the fourth scale degree - of `D` major. This is really important to understanding the harmonic gesture. It doesn't start on the tonic, it's a gentle fall from up at the subdominant down to the tonic. It's like a little sigh of relief that sets the whole mood. The point is we can make these observations about up/down until we know where tones lie in the tonality, in the scale.
- The top note of the first two chords `F#` is the *mediant*. Again, this tone's identify in the tonality is important. First, it's the tone that determines whether the mode is major or minor! Also, melodies starting on or moving about the mediant often have a sweet, lyrical quality and that is apparent in this music.
- Fast forward to the end and look at the mediant. It becomes `F` natural, a minor third above the tonic. That lends a certain gravity to the end. It gets kind of heavy, brooding. That plays with the special role of the mediant.
- When the melody proper starts in bar 5, notice it starts on the mediant, but also notice that the melody *outlines the tonic chord `D` major.* That demonstrates the *filling in the tonic chord* idea. Also some of the tendency tone stuff can be seen: `G` moves down to `F#` (`^4` to `^3`) and `C#` moves up to `D` (`^7` to `^1`), there is also a `B` down to `A` (`^6` to `^5`) but the motions is "delayed" by two beats.

I'm not sure this is the thing you are struggling with, but it is what comes to my mind when reading your question.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. But how do you envision this when playing? To me this answer sounds like a first introduction to musical analysis, not something that you can do while playing.

Comment: You need to be much clearer about how you use the word "vision" while simultaneously asking to disassociate the matter from a particular instrument. If you truly remove the instrument it _IS_ pure theory. When I visualize I think of an instrument - piano or guitar - or I just think of staff lines. I suppose I'm just pragmatic. Visualizing something else is just so many steps removed from either my hands on an instrument or reading notation.

Comment: If I try to super condense all the interval stuff, I'd say I think about single step motions, especially half steps motions and their harmonic meaning in the key. Things like FA down to MI, TI up to DO. Or, did TI get lowered so we are probably moving to the subdominant. The same gets expanded a bit to harmonic outlines like a minor sixth contracting in by a half step to a perfect fifth, from the upper voice it's a kind of subdominant to tonic move, from the lower voice a dominant to tonic move. That's the kind of thing I'm noting while playing.

Comment: Style-wise I'm talking about Baroque/Classical. In that style harmony is very much about tonic/dominant on various tonal centers. So it's all about moves to and from the tonic. When it isn't tonic/dominant, it's typically modulating - often with sequential harmony - at that point the whole notion of key center is in flux and a bit off topic.

Comment: Well maybe I need to ask a Sax player^^ they will probably not be thinking like that.

Comment: Right now your question only has 57 view. Give other people time to answer. There are all types on the forum! Also, give yourself time for all these responses to sink in. You might get an answer where it all clicks into place for you... or you may need to spend a lot of time thinking, playing,and thinking about your playing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to tell you how I approach playing, soloing, scale studies, and just about everything musical. First off I study a lot, an awful lot. Everything I study, I try to get to the point that it becomes automatic, kind of like speaking. If a thought comes into my head that I wish to communicate, the words are automatically there for me and I can say them automatically. That's also the way I play my music. I can hear another person in the band play something that inspires a response in me and so I play the response automatically. It can sound like everyone's talking at the same time, or it can come out sounding like a more polite conversation, depending how courteous the band members are. One point I'd like to make is that along with the automatic response that I try to achieve, I also try to keep it relatively simple and straight forward. When I play, I want to convey feelings and emotions, paint invisible pictures with the sound of my instrument. I can do that because I know what I can trust my hands and my instrument to do and they do it automatically. It wasn't always the case for me, but I kept at it and I found it happening for me. That's just my personal experience. I'm adding an afterthought here: Somewhere in my studies I came across several pages of Melodic Patterns. These are exercises that I practiced until they became automatic for me. I can hear these patterns in my head and play them as if I were speaking. I suppose you could probably find more information about them by googling "Melodic Patterns" for what ever instrument you're interested in

Comment: Yeah I get the feeling that I just have to keep on keeping on and find my own way through it ^^. I am getting better at knowing where the notes are, in a musical sense, not on the guitar, but this is probably the kind of stuff that you just have to do for a year and then you don't even know how you started because it is so second nature...

Comment: @pindakaas- I look at it in a way such that I'm talking using my instrument. When I speak using my voice, although I can spell the words I'm using, that is not what I'm thinking about as I'm speaking. It's much the same way when I'm playing music.

Comment: @pindakaas- Please note the afterthought added at the end of my answer.

Comment: Interesting, sounds usefull, will defenetly be looked at and probably studied. ^^

Answer (score 0):

In this video, guitar scales are visualized, quite literally, in different ways, from simple to complex: as plain dots showing the scale shapes, colored dots showing chord notes, and finally as scale/mode degrees.

I'm linking to the point in the video where the scale degrees are visualized, since that's what you asked specifically, but if you want to get to the bottom of the whole issue you should probably take the time to watch the whole thing from the beginning. (It's not easy and it's not short, but I think it will answer pretty much everything you asked in the question)

For full disclosure, I worked on designing the software shown in the video, which is called the Guitar Scales Method.

Comment: As this is guitar specific it's not really what I need.

Comment: @pindakaas, now that I understand the question better, the piano-specific approach that I would suggest, tentatively, would be to use seventh chords in root position (i.e. no inversions) as the basis for the visualization. For example, if you want to think in D, visualize a Dmaj7 chord in root position (D F# A C#). That shows you instantly where the root, 3rd, 5th and 7th degrees are. The remaining degrees can be inferred easily. So, while improvising in D, playing Gymnopedie, etc. if you can visualize that Dmaj7 it should tell you a lot about all the scale degrees' positions on the keyboard.